# Aligning 4 div boxes that are separating into 2 groups on different levels?

Tags: html, inline

I am having difficulty aligning 4 div boxes inline.

they are separating into 2 groups of two on different levels.

Here is a link to the page they are on (they are the pink boxes at the bottom):http://ra-ra-superstar.myshopify.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete float property on your 4 img element and add this css :

```
#bottom-cont{clear:both;}

.imageBox{float:left;}
```

Comment: Hi,

Have followed your advice but 1 box is still going bellow the others. Do you have any advice o how to fix this?

Comment: Test with .imageBox img {...} . ([look my Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/ELmDz) ) and verify your html structure